# How to distinct limit for every data

Tags: mysql

Accept my best wishes dear friends, I have a problem related with mysql table. Actually I've a table like this

[image: mysql Table]

Now I want to query last purchase tax for every product code. for this i use this mysql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROD_CODE, PURCHASE_TAX
FROM PRODUCT_STOCK
WHERE PROD_CODE
IN ( 5300,  'BLUEBOOK' ) 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

from doing this mysql returning result set like this

[image: Result Set]

As you can see in result set mysql return all row of related product. while i want only last row. Please help me for this

Comment: please format ur question and write in english and avoid native language. I can understand what u wrote but many will not.

Comment: It's okay @AbhikChakraborty. I'll take care of it next time, please help me in this time.

Comment: I wonder you are not bad in English then why you tried to wrote in Hindi? By this you loose lot of answers from around the world. I can understand what u wrote but many will not. So Please take care of it next time.. Cheers!

Comment: I think I've got the answer for your query.Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I see no column to show time, I am assume all the records are inserted in serial order, hence greater the id, the more recent the record is.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PROD_CODE) AS CODE, (SELECT PRODUCT_STOCK.PURCHASE_TAX FROM PRODUCT_STOCK WHERE PRODUCT_STOCK.PROD_CODE = CODE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS PURCHASE_TAX
FROM PRODUCT_STOCK
WHERE PROD_CODE
IN ( 5300,  'BLUEBOOK' );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this query return only first product data not to all.

Comment: I've updated the query. Can you share the result screen shot? It can be easily fixed.

Comment: santosh this is my result set for your query http://lpgbookkeeping.in/test/Untitled2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try with GROUP BY like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROD_CODE, PURCHASE_TAX
FROM PRODUCT_STOCK
WHERE PROD_CODE
IN ( 5300,  'BLUEBOOK' ) 
GROUP BY PROD_CODE;
```

Comment: I was try this but it is returning result set which is not in my use.

Comment: are you used `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: yes i was used but result set return only first row of every product

Comment: can you post your expected output?